# Sorting by two columns

Tags: text-processing, awk, sort

Write a shell script named `sales1` using `nawk` and `sort` commands to do the following:
1. print the file in two sections, east and west, with lines alphabetized by last name
within each section, showing per quarter and total sales per person.
2. print the names of sales people in three groups:
"The following people had total sales greater than $270:"
"The following people had total sales between $250 and $270:"
"The following people had total sales less than $250:"

```
east:Sam Smith:52:72:78:62  
east:Daniel Liebelt:83:78:84:61  
east:Shirley Couts:66:57:67:37  
east:James Peringer:50:62:56:94  
east:Lilly Batsuro:58:85:84:52  
west:Alex Opitz:79:68:57:93  
west:Carmen Gondar:62:58:85:56  
west:Derek Willard:63:69:74:43  
west:Kim Husak:89:91:63:64  
west:Lenny Taufa:53:61:82:52
```

I only need assistance with # 1...

I've tried

```
sort -k1,1 -k2,2
```

But it only sorts it by east then west and not by the last name. I'm trying to treat the first column as the direction and first name and the second column as the last name with the numbers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk` you could prepend `:` to the last field (that is, last name plus everything that follows) `sort` by 1st and 3rd fields (this time using `:` as a field delimiter) then again with `awk` remove the first `:` from the last field :

```
awk '$NF=":"$NF' infile | sort -t : -k1,1 -k3,3 | awk 'sub(/:/, "", $NF)'
```

end result:

```
east:Lilly Batsuro:58:85:84:52
east:Shirley Couts:66:57:67:37
east:Daniel Liebelt:83:78:84:61
east:James Peringer:50:62:56:94
east:Sam Smith:52:72:78:62
west:Carmen Gondar:62:58:85:56
west:Kim Husak:89:91:63:64
west:Alex Opitz:79:68:57:93
west:Lenny Taufa:53:61:82:52
west:Derek Willard:63:69:74:43
```

Comment: Is this possible to do with nawk instead of sed?

Comment: `nawk` ? why did you tag your question `linux` ? what's your _OS_ ?

Comment: Oh sorry that was a mistake. I'm currently using debian. The assignment requests that I use nawk and sorting commands. Which is why I'm asking

Comment: @Han - for your information: debian is a linux distro. Also, if this is homework post the exact requirements and tell us what have you tried.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Sorry I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r 's/^([^:]+):([^ ]+) ([^:]+):.*$/\1-\3 &/' your-file.txt  | \
    sort | sed -r 's/[^ ]+ (.*)/\1/'
```

Example:

```
$ sed -r 's/^([^:]+):([^ ]+) ([^:]+):.*$/\1-\3 &/' your-file.txt  | sort | sed -r 's/[^ ]+ (.*)/\1/'
east:Lilly Batsuro:58:85:84:52
east:Shirley Couts:66:57:67:37
east:Daniel Liebelt:83:78:84:61
east:James Peringer:50:62:56:94
east:Sam Smith:52:72:78:62
west:Carmen Gondar:62:58:85:56
west:Kim Husak:89:91:63:64
west:Alex Opitz:79:68:57:93
west:Lenny Taufa:53:61:82:52
west:Derek Willard:63:69:74:43
```

By the way, this is how `sort` selects the first field and the second field when you run it with `sort -k1,1 -k2,2`:

```
$ sort --debug -k1,1 -k2,2 ttt.txt
east:Daniel Liebelt:83:78:84:61
___________
           ____________________
_________________________________
east:James Peringer:50:62:56:94
__________
          _____________________
_________________________________
east:Lilly Batsuro:58:85:84:52
__________
          ____________________
________________________________
east:Sam Smith:52:72:78:62
________
        __________________
____________________________
east:Shirley Couts:66:57:67:37
____________
            __________________
________________________________
west:Alex Opitz:79:68:57:93
_________
         __________________
_____________________________
west:Carmen Gondar:62:58:85:56
___________
           ___________________
________________________________
west:Derek Willard:63:69:74:43
__________
          ____________________
________________________________
west:Kim Husak:89:91:63:64
________
        __________________
____________________________
west:Lenny Taufa:53:61:82:52
__________
          __________________
```